# promises scope using await and async

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

```
      var accountA;
       var  accountB;
      accounts = async () => {
        accountA = await server.loadAccount(Apub)

        console.log(accountA)
        accountB = await (server.loadAccount(Bpub))
    }

  accounts()

  console.log(accountA);
```

1) Apub is my public key which i have already declared

2)when i am printing the

> accountA

inside the function it is showing me complete details from accountA

3) when i do console.log outside the function, the output is

> undefined

4) i have declared the variables outside the function as  the global scope

please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you are using `await` inside the function you are not waiting till it you get a response while you call `accounts` which is an async function

```
var accountA;
var  accountB;
accounts = async () => {
    accountA = await server.loadAccount(Apub)

    console.log(accountA)
    accountB = await (server.loadAccount(Bpub))
}

accounts().then(() => {
    console.log(accountA);
})
```

If you have the above code in a function which is async then you could use await with `accounts` too

```
await accounts()
```

Comment: Thnks 

But i am little confused i have init   the value inside  the function   but why i can't see the value

Comment: That is because your console.log after accounts() is executed while the async request inside accounts are still in process.You must read about event loops in javascripts to know more

Answer (score 1):

Your `accounts` function is asyncronous. So the console.log() in the last line is called first, before accounts has time to finish. This is why it displays undefined. You have to wait for `accounts` to finish before printing it by adding an "await" before your call.

```
var accountA;
var  accountB;
accounts = async () => {
    accountA = await server.loadAccount(Apub)

    console.log(accountA)
    accountB = await (server.loadAccount(Bpub))
}

await accounts()

console.log(accountA);
```